# Pulling from SQL database using Entity Framework ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project but this is just for practice, I did one quick code on console app

Class C is the model entity.

`CDataContext` is the database context

`CRepository` is where I am trying to perform CRUD features

Here is my code :

```
class C
{
    [Key]
    public int C_Id { get; set; }   
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public C( string A1)
    {
        Name = A1;
    }
}

class CDataContext:DbContext
{
   public  DbSet<C> Context { get; set; }
}

class CRepository
{
    public CDataContext dbContext = new CDataContext();

    public bool AddList(C c)
    {
        // works perfectly and even updates the database
        dbContext.Context.Add(c);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }

    public List<C> DisplayAll()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
        /* Throws error: Exception has been thrown by the target 
         * of an invocation
         * */
        var value = dbContext.Context.ToList();
        return value;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        C Cobj = new C("Dero");

        CRepository O = new CRepository();

        Console.WriteLine(O.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
        // add values to database but throws error on DisplayAll
        //O.AddList(Cobj);
        //Error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
        O.DisplayAll();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error Message: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

`AddList` works, and updates database but display all throws:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: There's more to the exception details than that, could you edit your question?

Comment: More on error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The class 'StringReplace1+C' has no parameterless constructor.

Comment: What happens if you give class `C` a parameterless, default constructor?

Comment: yes! it works perfectly! displays all data from db . Why is that it needed a constructor ?

Comment: When the dbContext gets data from the database and creates list of `C`, it creates objects if `C` to add to the list. Default constructor is used for creating intances because the EF code does not know what parameters to be passed to the parameterized constructors. So it creates instances using default constructor and sets their properties after that.

Comment: you CAN have constructor with parameter(s). But when you do so, it cancels default parameter-less constructor. So, in case of EF you need also manually add parameter-less constructor when you add one with parameters.

Comment: Thank you guys! I have better understanding of this situation now